# Java hangs on foreach loop

Tags: java, foreach, neo4j, blocking

Java seems to be hanging when incrementing a foreach loop. I can't find anybody out there with a similar problem, so maybe I'm just doing something wrong, but I can't imagine what it is. I'm pulling out a set of Nodes from a Neo4J database, then iterating through it. I don't modify that set of Nodes during the loop, but after a while, it hangs. Here's the code that does it:

```
        IndexHits<Node> usrs = users.get("Type", "User");
        System.out.println("Operating on "+usrs.size()+" Users:");

        for (Node u : usrs) {
            System.out.print(".");
            if (inUserBlacklist(u))
                continue;
            System.out.println("HA");
        }
```

All that inUserBlacklist(u) does is check the Node u against a preset Set of Nodes to see if the Node is part of the blacklist. It doesn't change anything about the Node u.

Users is a Neo4J index, so calling get() on it should return an iterable IndexHits object. This foreach loop runs through the foreach loop 269,938 times. At the end of that iteration, it prints "HA", but then it never prints another ".". It just hangs at that point, right before iteration 269,939. That puts it as blocking on the foreach loop. There should be 270,012 total iterations.

I noticed that my blacklist contains 74 items, all of which should be matched once while going through this loop. 270,012 - 74 = 269,938, but that doesn't explain why it's blocking. All I can figure is that the foreach loop is incrementing the position on the iterator without incrementing its counter when I call continue. Then it gets to the end of the set and has nothing more, but the counter thinks it is only at 269,938 out of 270,012.

Do any of you know why a foreach loop would behave like this?

EDIT:
A stack trace shows that the process is indeed stuck on the for loop (line 116):

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
       at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pread0(Native Method)
       at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pread(FileDispatcher.java:49)
       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:248)
       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:224)
       at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:663)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceRow.readPosition(PersistenceRow.java:91)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.acquire(PersistenceWindowPool.java:177)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.acquireWindow(CommonAbstractStore.java:559)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.RelationshipStore.getChainRecord(RelationshipStore.java:349)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.getMoreRelationships(ReadTransaction.java:121)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.getMoreRelationships(ReadTransaction.java:104)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getMoreRelationships(PersistenceManager.java:108)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getMoreRelationships(NodeManager.java:666)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getMoreRelationships(NodeImpl.java:427)
       - locked <0x77c9b4a0> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.IntArrayIterator.fetchNextOrNull(IntArrayIterator.java:91)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.IntArrayIterator.fetchNextOrNull(IntArrayIterator.java:36)
       at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.next(TraversalBranchImpl.java:128)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.PreorderBreadthFirstSelector.next(PreorderBreadthFirstSelector.java:48)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserImpl$TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserImpl.java:127)
       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserImpl$TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserImpl.java:94)
       at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
       at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)
       at NodePlacement.LoadFromNode(NodePlacement.java:116)
```

So...it looks like the thread is still running and not blocked on anything. Yet it isn't getting out of this section of code. Maybe something about the setup of my database has put it into an infinite loop?

Comment: What does the `inUserBlacklist` method do? If you break into the debugger when it's "blocked" what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: You might want to enable GC logs and see whether Full GC is slowing down things?

Comment: just one question. How exactly did you analyze the results. You will have such a long series of .HA...( I am assuming that you programmed something to calculate the exact prints) . And for 74 cases you never print HA, could it be that your counting was wrong? somethimes the simplest things bite the hardest!

Comment: I initially included a counter and only started printing the HAs after 269,000 iterations. I also included a printout of the current counter. I removed that and ran it without it though, just to make sure that it still hangs with minimal code (Not that I thought I had something wrong with my counter that could cause it to hang. But then again, I didn't think I had anything wrong with this in the first place to cause it to hang.).

Comment: Could you perhaps share you full code in a gist?

Answer (score 0):

When it hangs, you can use Ctrl-Break from the command line or suspend execution if running under debugger, or use jps and jstack tools to get a thread dump of your application and see what method is being executed.

On a side note, all foreach loop does is retreving `Iterator` instance from an `Iterable` collection or array and use Iterator's hasNext() and next() methods. So, if any of those methods will hang, you'll get what you see now.

Comment: On Unix system, use 'kill -3 JAVA_PID' to dump all Thread stacktraces. `jconsole` can also help you achieve that with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that the problem is in code AFTER the loop.  As written, the code will print "HA" for all but the entries for which `inUserBlacklist()`..  If you're basing your assumption on programmatic counting of "HA" output lines, then the count you gave indicates the code finished the loop and went on to other things, which you haven't provided.

Comment: For the purpose of testing this, I made sure that the only things that happen after the loop are that I call finish() on the Neo4J transaction and then close the Neo4J database. The program terminates after that.

Comment: Can the `finish()` call hang? Can you add an println after your loop to verify that your code does not leave the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure if finish() can hang or not. It's part of the Neo4J library. Their documentation doesn't mention anything about whether or not the finish() or shutdown() calls can block. I have, however, verified that the code does not leave the for loop.

Comment: Then the only possibility left is that the iterator returned by `IndexHits.iterator()` is the problem.  In order to be usable in a for-each loop, it must implement `Iterable<Node>`, and the iterator it returns is used "under-the-covers" by Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never figured out exactly what was going on, but it seemed like the problem was happening in disk access on the Neo4J database. I went back and looked at the way I created it, and I realized that I had made a serious mistake in the way I created the database. I rebuilt the whole thing and I'm not having the issue now. Thank you everyone for your help!